# How to manipulate regex replacement strings in Elixir

Tags: regex, erlang, elixir

I found myself wanting to do this in Elixir:

```
re_sentence_frag = %r/(\w([^\.]|\.(?!\s|$))*)(?=\.(\s|$))/
Regex.replace(re_sentence_frag, " oh.  a DOG. woOf. ", String.capitalize("\\1"))
```

Of course, that has no effect.  (It capitalizes the string `"\\1"` just once.)  What I really meant is to apply `String.capitalize/1` to every match found by the `replace` function.  But the 3rd parameter can't take a function reference, so passing `&(String.capitalize("\\1")` also doesn't work.

This seems so fundamental that I'm surprised it's not possible.  Is there another approach that would as neatly express this kind of manipulation?  It looks like the underlying Erlang libraries would not immediately support passing a function reference as the 3rd parameter, so this may not be completely trivial to fix in Elixir.

How would you program manipulation of each matched string?

Comment: The `"\\1"` is meant for consumption by the regex engine, not the String class.

Comment: I would look if a function ref is a parameter option. Where the function recieves match results and returns the replacement string. If it can't do that, then you have to reconstruct a new string in a regex find loop.

Comment: Your best bet is use `scan` and use the information from the result to manually replace them. For code-reuse purpose, you can create a wrapper function that accepts a function as parameter.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I think you're correct, although I was leaning toward using split.  One of the goals above was to avoid changing the in-between bits, and it's not clear how to get those (or include them in the final results) using `scan`.  I'll post one possible answer based on `split`.

Comment: You are right. We can't pass a function to the Erlang side so it is non trivial to support this feature. :( Split seems to be the best way to go for this case.

Comment: If your language's `split()` function supports captured delimeter as array elements, you can split using a modified regex (from above) `(\w(?:[^\.]|\.(?!\s|$))*)(?=\.(?:\s|$))`. Then, after split, start a new string, for each element, check it against that regex for a match. If it matches, upper case it, then append. If not, just append.

Comment: If the split doesn't support captured delimeters, you can split on this `(?=\w(?:[^\.]|\.(?!\s|$))*)(?=\.(?:\s|$))`, then check each element for a match with `\A(\w(?:[^\.]|\.(?!\s|$))*)(?=\.(?:\s|$))(.*)\z`. If matched, group 1 is to be upper cased and appended, group 2 is the remainder to be appended. No match, just append the element. All split and matching functions are to be single line modifier `//s` or put `(?s)` modifier group at the start of all regex's.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution based on `split`:

```
" oh.  a DOG. woOf. pi is 3.14159. try version 7.a." |>
String.split(%r/(^|\.)(\s+|$)/)                      |>
Enum.map_join(&String.capitalize/1)
```

I guess it's not much more clumsy than my original attempt.  The regex is considerably simpler, as it only needs to find the bits between sentences.

Comment: I left some comments on `split` under your original posted question. Don't know if it will help or not.